# What is the distribution of the random variable $\max(x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

$x$ is a random vector that follows the $p$-dimensional normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,I_d)$. What is the distribution of the random variable $\max(x)$ ?

Comment: If $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_p)$, then $x_i$'s are independent standard normal. So just find the cdf of $\max x$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hints:**

1. $\ \max_\limits{1\le i\le p}x_i \le y\ $ if and only if $\ x_i\le y\ $ for all $\ i=1,2,\dots, p\ $.
2. $\ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p\ $ are independent.